# im trying to get the id of the user connected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, authentication

im doing a website where u can create an account ,when ur not connected , theres the login button and where u are connected theres the profil page and the logout boutton.
I want that when u click on the profil button, it redirects u to a page with ur id like /users/id where u can change ur bio and profile picture.

i use react, nodsjs express and mongo

i tried to set an userId and a setUserId that is initiate to null in UserContext

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const UserContext = createContext({});

export function UserContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({});
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ userId, setUserId }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

when u login , the id is put in userId, but it doesnt work , the url is users/null when i login and click on profile

heres the code of login

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "../../styles/LoginPage.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { UserContext } from "../UserContext";

function LoginPage({ isLoggedIn,setIsLoggedIn }) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const { setUserId } = useContext(UserContext);

  const login = async (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `http://localhost:8000/users/login`,
        {
          email,
          password,
        },
        {
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      );

      console.log(response);

      if (response.data.errors) {
        setErrorMessage("Erreur lors de la connexion");
      } else {
        setIsLoggedIn(true); // Mettre à jour l'état global de connexion
        setRedirect(true); // Définir la redirection
        setUserId(response.userId);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
      setErrorMessage("Informations incorrectes");
    }
  };

  if (redirect) {
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={login}>
      <h1 className="login-title">Login</h1>
      <input
        type="email"
        placeholder="Email"
        value={email}
        onChange={(ev) => setEmail(ev.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="password"
        placeholder="Mot de passe"
        value={password}
        onChange={(ev) => setPassword(ev.target.value)}
      />
      {errorMessage && <p className="error-message">{errorMessage}</p>}
      <button className="my-button">Connexion</button>
      <Link to="/register">
        <button className="my-button">Pas de compte ?</button>
      </Link>
    </form>
  );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

and heres the code of my layout where theres the button

```
import '../styles/Layout.css'
import skull from '../assets/bg3.gif'
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { UserContext } from './UserContext';


function Layout({isLoggedIn,setIsLoggedIn}) {
  const title_header = "True Crime Story";
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { userId } = useContext(UserContext);


  const handleLogout = async () => {
    try {
      // Effectuer les actions de déconnexion, tels que la suppression du cookie, etc.
  
      setIsLoggedIn(false);
      navigate("/login"); // Effectuer la redirection vers la page d'accueil ("/")
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during logout:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="header">
        <div className="main-title">
          <h1>{title_header}</h1>
        </div>
        <ul className="side-bar">
          <li><Link to="/">Accueil</Link></li>
          {isLoggedIn && (
            <>
              <li>
              <Link to={`/users/${userId}`}>Profil</Link>

              </li>
              <li>
                <button onClick={handleLogout}>Déconnexion</button>
              </li>
            </>
          )}
          {!isLoggedIn && (
            <li>
              <Link to="/login">Connexion</Link>
            </li>
          )}
          <li><Link to="/articles">Articles</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/infos">Infos</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="body">
        <div className="modal">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <Outlet />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src={skull} className="image-skull" alt="skull-gif" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you forgot to wrap the parent component of the `Layout` Component on a `UserContext` as described on the doc https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext.
SomeContext.Provider

> Wrap your components into a context provider to specify the value of
> this context for all components inside:
>
> ```
> function App() {  
>     const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');  
>     // ...  
>     return (
>     <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>
>       <Page />
>     </ThemeContext.Provider>   ); 
> }
> ```

You can start like this:

### Create the context

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const UserContext = createContext({});

export function UserContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({});
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ userId, setUserId }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

### Wrap your component tree with the context provider:

You need to wrap all of Component that need to use the context with Contextprovider. For example the `LoginPage`, `UserProfile` if you have one defined:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <UserContextProvider>
       {/* Your component tree goes here for example defining your route in Here*/}
    </UserContextProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Like that, you can access the content on the Components that are part of the tree using the `useContext` hook.

Comment: i already did what ur telling me in my file App , i want to send it to u , but it says my comment is too long

Comment: Can you give me a link to the source code ? maybe i may find the issue